# Hibernate Criteria query : trouble getting Set of a Domain object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a table which mimics the below column structure.

> ID, Harbor_Name, Country, Country_Code, State, State_Code,City

I have an entity Harbor as below.

```
public class Harbor{
   private Long Id;
   private String name;
   private Address address;
   -- getters and setters ---
}

Public class Address{
  private Country country;
  private State state;
  private String city;
  -- getters and setters ---
}

Public class Country{
  private String name;
  private String code;
  -- getters and setters ---
}

Public class State{
  private String name;
  private String code;
  -- getters and setters ---
}
```

I wanted to get Set from the table given a country name. I tried below criteria object and i am running into an SQL exception as below.

```
    public Set<State> getStatesByCountry(String countryName) {
    Criteria criteria = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Harbor.class, "harbor");
        criteria.createAlias("harbor.address", "a");
        criteria.createAlias("a.country", "c");
        criteria.createAlias("a.state", "s");
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("s.name")));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("c.name", countryName).ignoreCase());
        criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("s.name"));
        states.addAll(criteria.list());
}
```

SQL Generated and Exception:

```
select distinct state3_.Harbor_Name as y0_ from HARBOR_DATA this_ where lower(country2_.Harbor_Name)=? and state3_.Harbor_Name is not null

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "STATE3_"."Harbor_Name": invalid identifier

<class name="sample.package.Harbor" table="Harbor_data" mutable="false">
        <id name="Id" column="ID"></id>
        <property name="name" column="Harbor_Name" />
        <component name="address" class="sample.domain.Address">
            <property name="city" column="City" />
            <component name="state" class="sample.domain.State">
                <property name="code" column="State_Code" />
                <property name="name" column="State" />
            </component>
            <component name="country" class="sample.domain.Country">
                <property name="name" column="Country" />
                <property name="code" column="Country_Code" />
            </component>
        </component>
    </class>
```

Comment: Do you have all 3 entities mapped to one single table?

Comment: Yes.. I did it that way to leverage existing domain objects address, country and state.

Comment: How do you map the entities to column names? using XML or annotations?

Comment: Added to the question... I had to edit the original xml just to give an example of the hbm file. So ignore if there are any typos.

Comment: @Funtik, it is not what I wanted. I wanted distinct state names not harbor names. But I think i have a solution that works, but I still need to find out what/why is handled differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
public Set<State> getStatesByCountry(String countryName) {
    Criteria criteria = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Harbor.class, "harbor");
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("harbor.address.state.name")));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("harbor.address.country.name", countryName).ignoreCase());
        criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("harbor.address.state.name"));
        states.addAll(criteria.list());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your criteria like this:

```
Criteria criteria = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Harbor.class, "harbor");
        criteria.createAlias("harbor.address", "a");
        criteria.createAlias("a.country", "c");
        criteria.createAlias("a.state", "s");

        //note I've changed projection property to harbor name
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("harbor.name")));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("c.name", countryName).ignoreCase());
        criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("s.name"));
        states.addAll(criteria.list());
}
```

Comment: Hey.. Thanks for taking a stab at it though. This is a new learning for me.